# PHP - how to do GET request when username password is asked in a popup?

Tags: php, apache, curl, zend-framework

Using following method i can login to API:

```
$ curl -v "http://www.test.com/a/b/c?id=1234" -u user1 -LK -XGET;
```

But, In PHP how can i submit username/password which is asked by htpasswd popup?

```
public static function sendSMS($from, $to, $username, $password,  $text) {
      $text = rawurlencode($text);
      $uri = "https://www.voipbuster.com/myaccount/sendsms.php?username={$username}&password={$password}&from={$from}&to={$to}&text={$text}";      
      $ch = curl_init();
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $uri);
      //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );

      //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, '3');

      //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
      //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, false); //    
      //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postString);
      //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
      $result = curl_exec($ch);      
      curl_close($ch);    
  }
```

Comment: [curlopt_userpwd](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following options:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```